# Cannot use HTML web font debian

Tags: html, css, fonts

I do not really think it is because I am on debian (Jessie) but, I try to use customs font for my HTML page, I read many tutorials, but none of them work.
I use .ttf fonts.

I use visual studio code and when I write "font-family" it offers me to choose in a list of some fonts ; none of them work but the sans-serif and the serif one.

```
@font-face{
    font-family: 'MyWebFont';
    src: url('GeosansLight.ttf') format('truetype');
}
body{ font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'MyWebFont', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;}
```

Do you understand what the problem is?

If it can helps, my project architecture is

```
Project
.
./views
  home.html
.
./style
  style.css
  geosanslight-webfont.woff
  geosanslight-webfont.woff2
  stylesheet.css
  geosanslight-demo.html
  generator_config.txt
  /specimen_files
.
./font
  geosanslight-webfont.woff
  geosanslight-webfont.woff2
  stylesheet.css
  geosanslight-demo.html
  generator_config.txt
  /specimen_files
```

Comment: Can you please post your code?

Comment: If it's a custom font, you can use this [Webfont Generator](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) to convert your font for all web formats. It also provides the CSS files to easily add it to your code. Make sure you make a folder in your "root" folder to store the converted web fonts.

Comment: You should include other formats as well (svg, woff). If you have a webfont, you should have them (often with css provided).

Comment: I converted the font and unzipped the file in a fonts directory (and modified the path), I integrated woff and woff2 files but, still not working…But I think that when I write a non local URL, it has to work anyway, but it does not

Comment: I think it is debian now, because I send the project to an OS X and fonts worked…